# Como fazer um evento em mais de um caixa/botão/label ao mesmo tempo?

Tags: c#

Em vb.net eu usava um comando que era:

```
private sub txt1_LostFocus(object sender, EventArgs e) handles txt2.text, txt3.text
    sender.text = Ucase(sender.text)
end sub
```

Isso fazia com que todas as caixas de texto ficassem em Uper case assim que perdesse o foco. Quero realizar o mesmo tipo de ação em C# sem ter que ficar programando um leave para cada caixa de texto, como posso fazer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Os eventos são registrados na classe `NomeDoForm.Designer.cs`, por exmeplo se o form se chama Form1, tem  um arquivo "Form1.cs" e vai haver o "Form1.Designer.cs".

Se abrir essa class, vai ver que o evento está registrado lá, algo assim basedo nos nomes que tem no sua pergunta:

```
this.txt2.LostFocus+= new System.EventHandler(this.txt1_LostFocus);
```

Basta então regitrar o mesmo evento para quisquer outros controles semelhantes (a assinatura do método pode variar entre um Button ou TextBox):

```
this.txt2.LostFocus+= new System.EventHandler(this.txt1_LostFocus);
this.txt3.LostFocus+= new System.EventHandler(this.txt1_LostFocus);
```